# How to change the default <title> on the "Tomcat Web Application Manager" admin page http://localhost:8080/manager/html

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, configuration, tomcat7

The default "Tomcat Web Application Manager" page (i.e. at myserver:8080/manager/html) has a default title of:

```
<title>/manager</title>
```

Can I configure the  string and replace "/manager" with something more useful? If so, how? I am running multiple Tomcats and I want a way to differentiate them via .  There appears to be nothing that controls the  value in "../webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml".

Also, is there a way to change the text "**Tomcat Web Application Manager**" in the body of the manager page. This is the text right at the top of the page. The Tomcat manager page has no JSP page or HTML page that I can alter so it confusing on what options there are to customize it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the page title your only options are:

1. patching the Tomcat source code; or
2. extending the HTMLManagerServlet and overriding the list() method.

Much of the other text, including the "Tomcat Web Application Manager" is provided by a properties file that you can override.

You don't say which Tomcat version you are using so I am going to assume 7.0.x. The steps to use your own text are as follows:

1. Create the directory structure org/apache/catalina/manager under CATALINA_BASE/lib
2. Download this file https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/manager/LocalStrings.properties into that directory
3. Edit the text in the file as required
4. Start Tomcat and access the Manager app

Comment: Great, yes that works and I can change the main title text on the manager page with the "htmlManagerServlet.title" property. The HTML <title> is still "<title>/manager</title>" however, can the <title> tag be controlled with a properties setting?

Comment: No. As stated in my answer, the only way to change the title is by changing or overriding the source code.